# how can i select item in a form, change the background and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select one of the Item element, then change the background color to blue when selected (disable any other item from changing background color i.e. only one element can be selected) and then submit the form. I would only like to submit when one of the item is selected else alert.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').on('click', 'div', function(e) {        
    e.preventDefault();   
    $('#done').attr('disabled','disabled');     
    $('input').removeClass('bluebg');
    $('div').removeClass('bluebg');        
    $(this).addClass('bluebg');    

  });

  $('#ok').click(function() {
    if($('div').hasClass('bluebg'))
    {
      document.location.href='page.aspx';
    }
    else { alert('Item is not selected');}
  });        

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div id="item1">Item1</div>
    <div id="item2">Item2</div>
    <div id="item3">Item3</div>
    <input type="button" value="OK" id="ok" />
</form>
```

Here's how output should look:

[image]

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I've made what you have as a snippet. There isn't enough things defined to solve this yet. Please add your CSS and other relevant HTML. It could simply be you didn't define the `bluebg` class properly.

Comment: Code works fine for me.

Comment: @Mikey:when i do $('#ok').click() , for first time, it gives me alert but then the whole form's background is changed to blue.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. You are doing a redirect before form can submit and submit handler on form is prevented ....it will never submit

Comment: @charlietfl: it does submit to another page. the issue i'm having is when i submit or when i click 'ok', the whole form turns background into blue.

Comment: Please create demo that replicates this. Can use jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run your example, I downloaded the jquery version that I am showing in the head and basically I applied 3 things:

1) Keep the id of the selected item with the variable selectedId.
2) Change your button input for a submit input and add the image with CSS.
3) Add a hidden input to store your selection.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.bluebg {
    background-color: blue;
}
.ok-button {
    /* Change this for your image location */
    background: url(OK.gif); 
    /* Adjust according to your image */
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
</style>
<script>
    var selectedId = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('bluebg');
            if (selectedId != null) {
                $('#' + selectedId).removeClass('bluebg');
            }
            selectedId = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#myItem').val(selectedId);
        });
        $('#myForm').submit(function() {
            if (selectedId != null) {
                return true;
            } 
            alert('Item is not selected');
            return false
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="page.aspx" method="POST">
        <div id="item1">Item1</div>
        <div id="item2">Item2</div>
        <div id="item3">Item3</div>
        <input id="myItem" name="myItem" type="hidden" /> 
        <input type="submit" class="ok-button" value="" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

your code works:

**EDIT:** my suggestion is to add an identifier to your form, and use more specific selectors, because with `$('div').removeClass('bluebg');` you're removing the class from all of your divs inside the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').on('click', 'div', function(e){        
        e.preventDefault();   
        $('#done').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#myform input').removeClass('bluebg');
        $('#myform div').removeClass('bluebg');        
        $(this).addClass('bluebg');    
                
    });

    $('#ok').click(function(){
        if($('#myform div').hasClass('bluebg'))
        {
            document.location.href='page.aspx';
        }
        else { alert('Item is not selected');}
    });
});
```

```css
form div {
  padding:10px 0;
}
.bluebg {
  background:blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <div id="item1">Item1</div>
    <div id="item2">Item2</div>
    <div id="item3">Item3</div>
    <input type="image" src="OK.gif" id="ok" />
<form>
```

Comment: the problem is when i do $('#ok').click() , i get the whole form background blue. How would i prevent it?